# NumberPicker change color of one item

Tags: android, kotlin, numberpicker

I'm trying to make a custom NumberPicker with String. The first String is "select..." and i want to make it a bit transparent to show this is not a real choice.

I tried to do things like

```
val placeholder = picker.getChildAt(0) as EditText
val placeholderColor = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(picker.textColor, 128)
placeholder.setTextColor(placeholderColor)
```

First point : The color change but when i scroll the picker, the color come back to this original color.
Second point : my `picker.childCount` return 1 but i give a list of 5 elements.
Third point : when i click on one element (what ever it is) he take the transparent Color

I think i don't understand something please help if you have any idea to help me ! :)

Comment: Could you let us know what component you are using for number picker?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker